# Is it possible to show a message text on the chart of Billboard.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, billboard.js

I'm working with [Biilboard.js](https://naver.github.io/billboard.js/), a library which is based on D3.

I created a chart and I want to be able to show a message on it, for example if Y-axis is greater than 100 or anything like this, doesn't matter the condition.

This is an example of what I want which is done with pure D3 (I guess):

[image]

Basically, if that condition is fulfilled, that message box appears over the chart.

Do you have any ideas of to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There're several ways to do that.

- 1) Add y Axis grid text
- 2) Simply, add some normal DOM element(ex. div, etc.) and handle it to be positioned over chart element

I'll try put some example using the first one and check for the [ygrids()](https://naver.github.io/billboard.js/release/latest/doc/Chart.html#ygrids) API doc.

```js
// variable to hold min and max value
var min;
var max;

var chart = bb.generate({
 data: {
  columns: [
   ["sample", 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250]
  ],
  onmin: function(data) {
   min = data[0].value;
  },
  onmax: function(data) {
   max = data[0].value;
  }
 }
});

// add y grids with deterimined css classes to style texts added
chart.ygrids([
 {value: min, text: "Value is smaller than Y max", position: "start", class: "min"},
 {value: max, text: "Value is greater than Y max", position: "start", class: "max"}
]);
```

```css
/* to hide grid line */
.min line, .max line{
    display:none;
}

/* text styling */
.min text, .max text{
    font-size:20px;
    transform: translateX(10px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/billboard.js/dist/billboard.min.css" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/billboard.js/dist/billboard.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <title>billboard.js</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="chart"></div>
</body>
</html>
```